# How to get text of <summary> inline, but text of <details> block?

Tags: html, css, summary

In closed state it should look like

```
Some-words-before [>] Summary-text
Some-more-words-after-all-the-stuff.
```

and in opened state

```
Some-words-before [v] Summary-text
Details-text
Some-more-words-after-all-the-stuff.
```

The code

```
Some-words-before <details><summary>Summary-text</summary>Details-text</details> Some-more-words-after-all-the-stuff.
```

results in

```
Some-words-before
[>] Summary-text
Some-more-words-after-all-the-stuff.
```

and

```
Some-words-before
[v] Summary-text
Details-text
Some-more-words-after-all-the-stuff.
```

So how to avoid/suppress the linebreak between "Some-words-before" and "[>] Summary-text"? Using `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` moves also "Details-text" onto the same line, which is not desired.

Comment: Please read [ask] and **[mcve]** before posting a question.

Comment: The details element probably cannot be made to work the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with CSS only without breaking markup.

If it's an absolute must, JS can be used to calculate the width of `.before` and set it as a CSS variable to apply a negative margin.

```js
document.querySelector(".details-text").style = `
  --offset: -${document.querySelector(".before").offsetWidth}px;
`
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.before {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.details-text {
  margin-left: var(--offset);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span class="before">Some-words-before </span>
    <details>
      <summary>Summary-text</summary>
      <p class="details-text">Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text Details-text
      </p>
   </details>
</div>
Some-more-words-after-all-the-stuff.
```

Comment: Why the `class="details"`?

Comment: Not needed - An unused remnant of my experimentation, removing.

Comment: The JS-code is inside a <script>-tag? (Sorry, if this question is naive.)

Comment: Yes, and ideally it should be re-run on resize event